# addProblemFactChange() stops working after "Bailing out of neverEnding selector (..) to avoid infinite loop."

Tags: optaplanner

I have in solverConfig.xml defined filterClasses

```
<localSearch>
      <unionMoveSelector>
          <changeMoveSelector>
              <filterClass>...</filterClass>
          </changeMoveSelector>
          <swapMoveSelector>
              <filterClass>...</filterClass>
          </swapMoveSelector>
          <tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
              <filterClass>...</filterClass>
          </tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
      </unionMoveSelector>
      (...)
<localSearch>
```

And in some cases, when there is no moves in log I can see WARN's:

> Bailing out of neverEnding selector (..) to avoid infinite loop.

Which is fine, but after some changes are made and `addProblemFactChange` is called algoritms do not start working again. Restarting works fine, so it is some problem with this method.

`solver.isSolving()` is returning true.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Try upgrading to `7.32.0.Final` first, we recently did some improvements what happens when all entities are pinned or when there are no entities. That sometimes caused that warning.

Comment: Is version 7.32.0.Final already available? I don't see this version on Maven Central Repo or optaplanner page (only 7.32.0-SNAPSHOT).

Comment: Any day now - we're waiting the ok from the sanity checks by the other kie projects. But a recent 7.32.0-SNAPSHOT from the jboss repository is enough to verify if that fix fixes it or if it's another problem.